# What do Claudia and Adam really want?

Tags: dark

On the TV show *Dark*, Claudia and Adam seem to be on opposite sides of the conflict to  control time travel, or whatever it is. However, it's unclear what they are actually aiming for, despite their many statements with respect to the matter.

They both say they want to fix everything and break the time loop, assuming that's even possible. But then they *both* tell people they must let things  play out as they always have in order to do this. They both claim that they're fighting for the "light" and their opponents for the "darkness", in those specific words or rather their German equivalents. They or their proxies both claim that their opponents want to "kill all of us" (Adam about Claudia, via Noah telling Helge) or "destroy everything" (Claudia about Adam).

Perhaps the clearest statement we get is Jonah's claim that "Adam and Sic Mundus want to create a new world; you and I want to save this one", but since they both seem to be trying to alter the past it's not at all clear what the distinction is.

So what exactly are their actual goals?

Comment: As far as I know we're supposed to be asking this question and not know the answer.  If I have some time and remember I might outline some details later.

Comment: This question cannot be answered before the last season is broadcast. It is part of the experience that you feel like Jonah or Noah who have limited perspective as well. So it is pure speculation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, we have an answer. It turns out that these descriptions are all accurate, due to the ambiguity of the language.

Adam wants to destroy everything, both his world and Eve's. He wants to kill his and Eve's child before it is born, thus, he expects, destroying the two worlds.  Claudia's statement is correct, but the only reason her goal can't quite be described as destroying everything as well is because she knows of the existence of the origin world. He tries to preserve events within the knot in order to fulfill his own personal past and arrive at a point where he can put his plans into action.

Claudia actually seems to want the same thing, but she actually knew how to do it. She arguably did want to kill everyone, so that was not a lie, but since Adam did not necessarily know that and since his goal was the same, in the end, presumably he was simply lying in order to recruit Helge. She tries to preserve events so that she can arrive at a point where she can tell Adam how to break the loop.

The middle Jonas seems to have been misinformed about Claudia's goals, probably by Claudia herself. Then again, if she had said something like "I want to preserve the original world," it is easy to see how this would have been both true and misinterpreted. Similarly, he may have *thought* Adam wanted to create a new world, presumably because that is what he had been telling all his followers, without knowing his true goal.

As a bonus answer, Eve has the simplest motivation.  She wants to preserve the time loop so that her and Jonas's child survives, so her motivations are most clear. It seems as if Adam may have been under the impression that Claudia was working for Eve, not least because she actually was for a while, which explains some of the things he said about her.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote...this is correct..

Comment: This seems like a correct and complete answer. Though you didn't mention Regina, as Claudia clearly knows that destroying the split world *won't* kill Regina, but rather save her life

Comment: Adam isn't lying when he says he wants to create a new world, he wants to create one of nothingness/dark (I'm assuming this is the reason for the show's name as Jonas/Adam are the main protagonist/antagonist).  He states this goal a few times.  Claudia wants to save Regina, until the final cycle, then she wants to end the cycle.  She realized she can't save Regina; ref: "letting go of what we want" speech.  Eve's motivations are the simplest, mainly because she gets to live a few happy years, she is being naive.  She loses her innocence, but never her naivety, unlike Jonas who is ready to die.